# Understanding steps of calculating discriminants.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, primitive-roots, discriminant

Here is the question I am asking about some steps in its keen answer:

[For $n =3,$ write $\Delta^2$ as an element of $A = \mathbb{Q}[e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}.]$(manually)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3862302/for-n-3-write-delta2-as-an-element-of-a-mathbbqe-1-e-2-e-3)

**The answer is given below:**

What a strange hint. There's a much better way to do it, and I have no idea why the author didn't set $a_3 = 1$ from the start.

I learned this argument from David Speyer. Computing the discriminant as a polynomial in the $e_i$ is equivalent to computing the discriminant of the polynomial $f(x) = x^3 - e_1 x^2 + e_2 x - e_3$. Up to a translation, which does not affect the discriminant, we can remove the quadratic term from this polynomial: if we substitute $x = y + \frac{e_1}{3}$, then we get a new polynomial (brace yourself)

$$\begin{align} g(y) &= \left( y^3 + e_1 y^2 + \frac{e_1^2}{3} y + \frac{e_1^3}{27} \right) - e_1 \left( y^2 + \frac{2e_1}{3} y + \frac{e_1^2}{9} \right) + e_2 \left( y + \frac{e_1}{3} \right) - e_3 \\
 &= y^3 + \left( - \frac{e_1^2}{3} + e_2 \right) y + \left( -\frac{2e_1^3}{27} + \frac{e_1 e_2}{3} - e_3 \right). \end{align}$$

Set $p = - \frac{e_1^2}{3} + e_2, q = -\frac{2e_1^3}{27} + \frac{e_1 e_2}{3} - e_3$, so that this new polynomial can be written $g(y) = y^3 + py + q$. Now it suffices to compute the discriminant of this new polynomial as a function of $p$ and $q$, then plug in these expressions for $p$ and $q$ in terms of the $e_i$.

The point of doing this is that we've now removed most of the terms from the discriminant: $p$ has degree $2$, $q$ has degree $3$, and $\Delta^2$ has degree $6$, which implies that it must be some linear combination $ap^3 + bq^2$ of $p^3$ and $q^2$. So we only have two coefficients to compute. We can actually compute these coefficients by computing the discriminant of two *specific* polynomials:

- Set $p = -1, q = 0$. Then $g(y) = y^3 - y = y(y + 1)(y - 1)$ has roots $0, \pm 1$, so its discriminant is $\left( (0 - 1)(1 - (-1))( (-1) - 0) \right)^2 = 4$, which gives $a = -4$.
- Set $p = 0, q = -1$. Then $g(y) = y^3 - 1 = (y - 1)(y - \omega)(y - \omega^2)$ has roots $1, \omega, \omega^2$ where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity (satisfying $1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0$), so its discriminant is $\left( (1 - \omega)(\omega - \omega^2)(\omega^2 - 1) \right)^2 = (1 - \omega)^6 = (- 3 \omega)^3 = -27$, which gives $b = -27$.

So we get $\boxed{ \Delta^2 = -4p^3 - 27q^2 }$ (already a useful formula in practice), and substituting $e_1, e_2, e_3$ in gives the full cubic discriminant (of more dubious value; I have never used it).

**My questions are:**

In this part of the solution: "  * Set $p = -1, q = 0$. Then $g(y) = y^3 - y = y(y + 1)(y - 1)$ has roots $0, \pm 1$, so its discriminant is $\left( (0 - 1)(1 - (-1))( (-1) - 0) \right)^2 = 4$, which gives $a = -4$.

- Set $p = 0, q = -1$. Then $g(y) = y^3 - 1 = (y - 1)(y - \omega)(y - \omega^2)$ has roots $1, \omega, \omega^2$ where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity (satisfying $1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0$), so its discriminant is $\left( (1 - \omega)(\omega - \omega^2)(\omega^2 - 1) \right)^2 = (1 - \omega)^6 = (- 3 \omega)^3 = -27$, which gives $b = -27$.
  "
  1 -in the first paragraph why is the discriminant looks like that $\left( (0 - 1)(1 - (-1))( (-1) - 0) \right)^2 = 4$,, what are the first terms $0,1,(-1)$ in the brackets representing and similarly what are the second terms $0,1,(-1)$ representing? should not $a = -2$ instead?

2-In the second paragraph, why we are factorizing  $y^3 - 1$ in terms of roots of unity, why we needed that? why this root of unity satisfies $1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0$?

3-In the second paragraph, How in generally we calculate the discriminant of roots of unity?

Could anyone help me answer those questions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is always easier to calculate the discriminant of a trinomial by noting that $\Delta^2$ is equal to the Vandermonde Matrix times its transpose.

If the roots are $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n$ then we have
$$
\Delta^2=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 &\dots &1\\
\alpha_1&\alpha_2&\dots&\alpha_n\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\
\alpha_1^{n-1}&\alpha_2^{n-1}&\dots&\alpha_n^{n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 &\dots &1\\
\alpha_1&\alpha_2&\dots&\alpha_n\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\
\alpha_1^{n-1}&\alpha_2^{n-1}&\dots&\alpha_n^{n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}^{T}
$$
which is equal to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
s_0 &s_1 &\dots&s_{n-1}\\
s_1& s_2 &\dots &s_{n}\\
\vdots &\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
s_{n-1}&s_{n}&\dots&s_{2n-2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the $s_k:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}^{k}$ are the sums of the $k$-th powers of the roots. Hence $s_0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}1=n$, $s_1=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i=e_1$ (in your notation), and so on.

In the case of $X^{3}-1$ the roots are $1,\omega,\omega^2$, where $\omega:=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$.  As the coefficient of $X^2$ is $0$ we have that the sum of the roots is $0$.

Hence we see that $s_0=3$, $s_1=0$, $s_2=1+\omega^2+\omega^4=1+\omega^2+\omega=0$; and then recursively $s_3=3$, $s_4=0$ and so
$$
\Delta^2=
\begin{bmatrix}
3 &0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 3\\
0 & 3& 0\\
\end{bmatrix}=-27.
$$

We could as easily have done the cubic $X^3+pX+q$ this way: find $s_1$ and $s_2$ by hand the rest follow recursively as $X^{k+3}+pX^{k+1}+qX^{k}=0$ at the roots.

It is almost as easy to work out the discriminant of $X^n-1$: I leave it for you to check.

Comment: In the case of $X^{3}-1$ why the roots are $1,\omega,\omega^2$?

Comment: Does $k$ ranges from 0 to $n-1$?

Comment: I do not see why "$s_0=3$, $s_1=0$, $s_2=0$" .... could you please elaborate that?

Comment: Can you please explain to me what is the way used in the link I mentioned?

Comment: what do you mean by $s_{k}$ is the sums of kth power of the roots? do you mean  $1 + \alpha_{1} + .... + \alpha_{1}^{n-1} = s_{n-1}$?

Comment: I have annotated the answer. I think you should ask the person who answered your question last time about their solution.

Comment: Thank you so much ..... I already did .... but after you gave me this answer I understood the other answer :)